# Running an LCD keypad shield from a separate power source

Tags: power, lcd

I need to use a motor shield and an LCD keypad shield simultaneously hooked up to a single Arduino Mega Board. Since I can't physically stack them, I decided to reroute all the pins used for the LCD keypad shield. When I reroute all pins **except** the two power pins, the LCD and keypad work fine. But when I disconnect those 2 pins and connect them to any other power source than the Arduino Mega, it fails. The screen becomes either blank / jumble of illegible characters / brief moments of expected output followed by the same jumble.

This behavior is really strange since the power pins don't carry any information, they are just power sources. The LCD keypad shield shouldn't be able to discriminate whether the power is coming from the Arduino Mega or not - but it does. I checked with a voltmeter that all power sources I tried are DC 5V.

At first I thought this is because the `lcd.begin()` function is called only once, so I rewrote my code to re-initialize the lcd at every iteration. This doesn't solve the problem.

Here is a picture of the setup that works. (rerouting all pins *except* the power.) Ignore the location of analog input cable, since it doesn't do anything in the current code.

[image]

And one that fails. The only difference from above is the power source.

[image]

And my code.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// select the pins used on the LCD panel
LiquidCrystal lcd(28, 29, 24, 25, 26, 27);

void setup()
{
  lcd.begin(16, 2);              
  lcd.print("Hello World!");
}

void loop()
{
  lcd.begin(16, 2);             
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Hello World!");
  delay(1000);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Hello Again!");
  delay(1000);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a different power source, but the two circuit need to have a common ground, since all electrical signals are relative to ground. So connect a wire from GND on the LCD to GND on your Arduino and everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Those little 16x2 LCDs are quite prone to power fluctuations.  Even powered solely by an Arduino I've seen them run OK for a few minutes than turn to showing gibberish.  Ensure you have good power connections, bring your power in as close as possible.

Maybe a capacitor across the power input to the display might help.